# SQL - Average Quarter-Hour Persons (AQH)

Tags: sql

In radio broadcasting there is a term called, "Average Quarter-Hour Persons" aka (AQH), which can be defined as...as the average number of persons listening to a particular station for at least five minutes during a 15-minute period.

I am not quite sure how to start this in SQL as the listening sessions span between the different 15-minute buckets.

The 15-minute buckets are 0-15, 15-30, 30-45, and 45-60.

Here is an example from the creator of the metric, "*For example, 1:00-1:05, 1:00-1:10 or 1:00-1:15 each equal one quarter-hour of listening. But, 1:11-1:19 is 
not a quarter-hour of listening (there is not five minutes in either clock quarter-hour, 1:00-1:15 or 1:15-1:30).*"

Let's assume I have the following table where each row contains the radio station, the time a user started listening and the time the user stopped listening.  For sake of simplicity I am not including any sort of User ID, etc.

`radio_station varchar
session_start time
session_stop time`

How would I write the SQL to calculate said metric per hour?

Comment: Which rdbms you are using?

Comment: What happens with long sessions that go over midnight? Possibly for multiple days.

Comment: I would really suggest that you delete this question and ask another.  Use an appropriate tag.  Provide representative data and desired results.  Explain what quarter hours have to do with the full hour metric you are looking for.

Comment: Its actually pretty easy to google up *Average Quarter-Hour Persons* and get a clear description from any number of sites. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

This query work in sql server. Only question is how to handle those sessions that span or end at midnight, how they are represented.

Set up sample data:

```
declare @t table(session_start time, session_stop time)
insert @t values ('1:00','1:05'),('1:00','1:10'),('1:00','1:15'),('1:11','1:19')
```

Query based on a CTE. Create the time buckets. If CTEs are not available, create a table containing these entries instead., and rest of the query is unchanged.

```
;with valid_times as (
select convert(time,'00:00') as valid_start, convert(time,'00:15') as valid_end
union all
select dateadd(minute,15,valid_start), dateadd(minute,15,valid_end)
from valid_times
where valid_start<='23:30'
)
select valid_start, valid_end,
    sum(case when datediff(minute,
        case when session_start<valid_start then valid_start else session_start end,
        case when session_stop>valid_end then valid_end else session_stop end
        )>=5 then 1 else 0 end) as AQH
from valid_times
left join @t t on valid_end>=session_start and valid_start<=session_stop
group by valid_start, valid_end
```